# How to get value of getter in class C which was setted in Class A (which was declared in Class B)

Tags: java

I am having three classes Class A which set Value, class B where both getter and setters are created, Class B which get value (set in Class A)

Because I was creating new instances of Class B in Class A and Class C. I am not able to get value in class Cwhioch was set in Class A.

What I acknowlegeds is We need to pass the reference to Class C instance from class A to Class B.

But I dont know how to do so.

I tried with this code. I know the result it is not possible. I dont know how to do it.

```
public Class A {
    int X = 9;
    B b = new B();
    b.setValue(X);
}

public Class B {
    private float value = 0;
    public float getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(float value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public Class C {
    B b = new B();
    final float x = b.getValue();
}
```

I expect when I use getValue() method of class B in Class C. I am able to get the value putted in Class A by setValue() method

Comment: you can't because you are setting value in class `A`.

Comment: But there must we someway @jackjay

Comment: yepp. in class `C` instantiate class `A` object and access the class `B` object inside class `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may do that by adding public static property inside a Class. 
**Static** property are associated to the class directly. they can be called even without creating an instance of the class, ex: ClassName.propertyName.

```
public Class B {
   public static float value = 0;
}
```

inside Class A you can set B float value like this :

```
public Class A {
   B.value = 9;
}
```

and get the value :

```
public Class C {
    final float x = B.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create an object using the "new" keyword, remember that you are creating a new object and a new memory space is alloted to it.
Now in class C, when you create a new object of B, a new memory space is alloted to this instance b. 
(This instance b does not point to the same memory location that b in class A points to)
Immediately after the object is created, you are calling b.getValue() which will only give you the default value of "value".

> when I use getValue() method of class B in Class C. I am able to get
>   the value putted in Class A by setValue() method

In order to get the value set in A, you need to call getValue() of b -- 
the object b which is in class A 
(and not the object b which is declared in class C)

So you need to access it using `a.b.getValue()` in class C.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all the instance of class B in Class A and Class C are different.
2. You don't have any getter in A class to get the Class B field values
3. You can create a method in Class C and pass by reference of instance in Class A.

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

You may do that in the following way:

```
public class A {
    int X;
    B b;
    public A(int x, b b){
        this.b = b;
        this.b.setValue(X);
    }        
}

public class C {
    B b;
    public C(B b){
      this.b = b;
    }
    public float getX(){
       return b.getValue();
    }
}
```

Now you pass the same reference of B class to both class A and C as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  B b = new B();
  A a = new A(9,b);
  C c = new C(b);

  float x= c.getX();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!!

In the Constructor of ClassA, pass reference of ClassB and set the Value.

```
public class ClassA {   
int X=9;
ClassB b;
public ClassA(ClassB b){
    this.b = b;
    this.b.setValue(X);
}}
```

Similarly, In constructor of ClassC, pass reference of ClassB and call the method getValue() to retrieve the value set by classA.

```
public class ClassC {
ClassB b;
public ClassC(ClassB b){
  this.b = b;
}
public float getX(){
   return b.getValue();
}}
```

Class B has the setter and getter function. In the main function, create an instance for ClassB and pass the same reference to ClassA and ClassC.

```
public class ClassB {
private float value = 0;
public float getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(float value){
    this.value = value;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassB b = new ClassB();
      ClassA a = new ClassA(b);
      ClassC c = new ClassC(b);
      float x= c.getX();
      System.out.println(x);
}}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to solve my question thanks for your suggestions.

But I actually did it. I made my getter and setter static. Now I don't need to create reference again to get value.

My code

```
public Class A {
    int X = 9;
    B b = new B();
    b.setValue(X);
}

public Class B {
    private static float value = 0;
    public static float getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(float value){
        B.value = value;
    }
}

public Class C {
    final float x = B.getValue();
}
```